# Error using Delete Controller in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three tables:

```
QUESTIONS (PK: QuestionID)
REPLIES (PK:ReplyID)  
VOTES (PK:UserID, ReplyID)
```

Relationship between `QUESTIONS` and Table `REPLIES` is one-to-many. Similarly, I have one-to-many relationship between `REPLIES` and `VOTES`.

I have generated CRUD functionality controller for Question model by using MVC-Scaffolding which is working fine. But I have a problem with Delete controller which works only when there is **NO** reply inside question.

While debugging, I have noticed that **(bool)SaveChangesError** becomes true.

I have written "Delete" controller for "Replies" which works even if a reply contains "Votes".

```
public ActionResult DeleteReply(int? id, int returnId)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var query = db.Replies.Where(t => t.ReplyID == id).Delete();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = returnId });
}
```

Does any one know what could be the issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `.Delete()` on your context result?

Comment: And for that matter, what is `SaveChangesError` too?